# Can I start an application during system startup as non root?

Tags: solaris

I have a Tomcat server application running on a Solaris 10 server in my company. I have no root access so every time when the system reboots I must manually start the server again. Is it somehow possible to get an event or something when the system startup?

Our IS is outsourced and I really would like to avoid being dependent on any technician outside the company.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Linux: user defined daemons/services](http://serverfault.com/questions/322193/linux-user-defined-daemons-services)

Comment: Some parts are duplicates. But e.g. the @reboot argument in crontab is not supported in Solaris.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you can, get your outsource company to set up an RC or svcadm script to run at system start. This will be a one off piece of work, once it is in place Tomcat will start with the system, you will not be dependant on any technician.

If your outsourced IS is not very "on the ball" then another way might be to have a little cron job (assuming you are allowed to use cron) checking for your Tomcat process and starting it up if it's not running.

Answer (score 1):

It isn't pretty but would work:

Write a script that checks if your application is running, if not, start it. Then schedule this script in your user's crontab.